# Периодическое падение производительности процессора

Tags: postgresql

Имеем Linux Mint 17.3, postgresql 9.5, i5, ssd raid 0, база и система на разных дисках.
Как бы не настраивал конфиг, постоянно имеются такие просадки.  Куда копать?

```
fsync = on  
full_page_writes = on  
synchronous_commit = off
```

Пробовал с выключенным fsync, ситуация не изменилась.

[image]

upd. Замечено, если подключений ~100 то загрузка как выше, но если увеличить до 1000, то совсем печально:
[image]

Comment: А разве то что процессор не нагружен это плохо ? может у вас в это время не запущены задачи которые жрут все 100%

Comment: Обратите внимание, как синхронно меняются графики сети и процессоров. Очевидно, что периодически база становится  не нужна ее потребителям, видимо это у них какие-то перерывы в работе.

Comment: Уточню, задача у сервера -  синхронизация константных данных клиентам. Во время просадок данные ещё есть, клиенты подтвердили приём предыдущего пакета. Т.е. Оснований у сервера простаивать нет.